# How to get a specific object property, based on another object property?

Tags: javascript, json, api, destructuring

i am quite new to code. I am trying to get the restaurant's rating, based on the user's restaurant name search. The restaurant name is labelled in the json as dba: "restaurant name". I am trying to search through the json and if the dba matches the restaurant name, i wish to return the respective property of "grade" back to the user interface.

here is my code:

```
const api_url = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/43nn-pn8j.json";
const getAPI = () => {
  fetch(api_url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      displayAPI(data);
    });
};
function displayAPI(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

getAPI();
displayAPI();
```

Comment: what is the restaurant name and how exactly your output should look like?

Comment: The api has thousands of NYC restaurants and their ratings and other propers like phone number , inspection date etc. 

I will  have an html input where user types the restaurant name, and a submit button, and when submitted, the respective restaurant rating should be outputted in an html element. 

i know i need to tell javascript to parse through the object and find the index which has the specified restuarant name, then have it return the respective rating .